# Return Value of function shows undefined in Sqllite executeSql query javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, function, undefined

Everyone

While I am learning Javascript,

How i can capture a value from a row returned by a "SELECT ..." statement and return it to variable(here it is 'port') so that i can use that value in different function.

This is something I have been stumped with for over 1.5 days now.

Here is the code I have written,

```
function DBQuery(Port_Id)
{
var portid=Port_Id; 
var port="";

db.transaction(function (tx){

    tx.executeSql('SELECT port_name FROM vact_port where port_id='+portid+'', [],  function(tx, results){

    var lenPort=results.rows.length;

    if(lenPort == 0)
    {   
        alert("No ports found") ;
        return ;
    }

    port = results.rows.item(0).port_name;
    alert ("Inside Success" + port) ;  //This shows correctly


    //return port;
});
alert ("Inside Success" + port) ; //This shows "undefined"

 });
}
```

Thanks,
Sunasra

Answer (score 0):

Your `alert()` call is outside your callback.

`db.transaction()` appears to take an anonymous function as a callback, and call it with the transaction object. That call will happen *whenever the database gets around to it*. The call to `db.transaction()` *schedules* a call to the anonymous function to happen later. After you have scheduled that call, you call alert, using `port`, which has not been set yet.

You need to do all your work inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks @Sean I am calling that function by these two statement in other function  named Search  ....     var SPort=DBQuery(parseInt(results.rows.item(i).freight_source));
 
  
  var DPort=DBQuery(parseInt(results.rows.item(i).freight_destination));    and want store that function return value in SPort and DPort Variable.
 I am beginner in javascript So please excuse my ignorance

Comment: You can't do it like that, unfortunately. *All* the code that has to follow the DB query has to be done from the callback. (You can write a function and call it, but you can't return a value like that.)

Comment: Not really. Almost all of the javascript environments available today have asynchronous APIs. You might be able to find a synchronous API for your DB, but then you'll just get bitten by the next one. You're going to have to learn asynch programming to do practical work in javascript.